# Geometry nodes: unable to use "reflect" vector math tool

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

Perhaps I'm not that far from succeeding, but I can't figure out how to properly use the *reflect* option provided by the vector math node.

I want to mimic the way light paths reflect against a parabolic mirror, thus materialize the way its focal point distorts when rays come at a certain incident angle. The following allows me to create what I would call the incoming rays field (i.e. parallel rays coming from the sun in my scene). Then I was expecting to mix this vector with the *normal* vector of each face in order to indicate the direction of the reflected ray. I fear I'm not very clear. Here's the node setup

[image]

Could anyone give me a little push to solve this?

Thank you,

Vincent.

Edit: Something quite closer to the solution, but my rays point outwards, it's quite puzzling for a reflection, isn't it? I fear I am missing something crucial with Euler-to-vector transforms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noise, I solved my issue simply by applying a vector math *Scale* set to -1 to my output vector (before Align Euler to vector node). It works the way I wished.

Thanks for reading!

V.